# How to access the guest VM via VirtualBox Host-Only network iface?

Tags: windows, virtualbox, debian

There is host (debian 6, VirtualBox 4.0) and guest (windows server 2003 SP2).
ipconfig on guest says that IP is 10.0.2.15 & Gateway is 10.0.2.2. 
ifconfig -a on host doesn't show any IP addresses for vboxnet0. Ping from host to 10.0.2.15 has no result. So, how can I access the VM from host?

Comment: Can you ping 10.0.2.2 from the guest?

Comment: Yes, it pings from guest.